# How to load csv files into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Good Morning, I've been trying for some days to load data from a csv file into a table, BUT I found out how to do it if you have privileges to create a new directory objects.

I did it locally with both ways UTL_FILE and external tables, but, I need special privileges to do it.

But when I tried to do it online I found out that I haven't got those privileges so, I'd like to find out if there's any way to do it without them.

Thank you!

PS: The two approaches are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  A varchar2(25);
  B number;
)
```

WITH UTL_FILE:

```
PROCEDURE load AS
    F UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    V_LINE VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_A varchar2(25);
    v_B number;

BEGIN
    F := UTL_FILE.FOPEN (<directory>, '<csv file>', 'r');
    IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F) THEN
        LOOP
            BEGIN
                UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F, V_LINE, 1000);

                IF V_LINE IS NULL THEN
                    EXIT;
                END IF;

                v_A  := REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_LINE, '[^;]+', 1, 1);
                v_B  := REGEXP_SUBSTR(V_LINE, '[^;]+', 1, 2);

                INSERT INTO test(v_A, v_B);
                COMMIT;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    EXIT;
            END;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;

    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F);
END load;
```

WITH external tables

```
PROCEDURE loadcsv AS
    A varchar2(25);
    B number;

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test select * testload;
    COMMIT;
END loadcsv;
```

HAVING

```
CREATE TABLE testload 
(   
  A VARCHAR2(25)
  B number
) 
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY "PRUEBAS"
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  ( records delimited by newline
    fields terminated by ';'
  )
  LOCATION
  ( 'Log_CSV_REND_SICTG_20170507.csv'
  )
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED ;
```

Comment: If you can add data to a table without the necessary privileges, then what you are doing is exploiting a security vulnerability/hacking, so no you can't

Comment: I can add data to the table, but I don't have enough privileges to create directory objects

Comment: I quote your question "*I need write privileges to do it. But when I tried to do it online I found out that I haven't got those privileges so, I'd like to find out if there's any way to do it without them.*" - that supports my comment. But if that is not the case, you need to reword your question to make it clearer.

Comment: That's true, Is clearer now?

Comment: Are you trying to add to an existing table, or a new one?

Comment: An existing one

Comment: Then I suggest you use something like http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm to convert your csv file to a sql query you can use

Comment: what about old , good and fast? sqlloader  Have you considered this option?

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz thanks, but I can't use anything but plain plsql

Comment: @CalvT that's a nice tool but i don't think is efficient if you have a large file

Comment: @DavidMarínSánchez I've used it (or similar) with 1000+ table rows, around 10/15 columns

Comment: SQL*Loader is a client-side tool that is as fast as extenal tables and faster than UTL_FILE. However if the requirement is to pull the data in from within stored PL/SQL then it won't help, and a server directory is going to be required. Normally one would already have been set up for this purpose.

Comment: I believe External Tables use the SQL*Loader engine.  So if you went the SQL*Loader route it would take very little effort to convert from the External Table.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try loading with SQL Loader. It is easy to use and very fast. You have to create a control file that describes how the data will be loaded, and needs to have the same structure as the table you're trying to load into. For you case it might look something like this.

**test.ctl**

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE <yourfilepath>
APPEND INTO TABLE TEST
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
    A,
    B
)
```

Then, from the command line.

```
host sqlldr username/password control=youfolder\test.ctl 
log=yourfolder\test.log
```